# Use clang to translate Linux kernel source code into LLVM bitcode

Tags: clang, llvm

I am trying to use LLVM to do some static analysis on some programs. Specifically, I am targeting Linux kernel source code. However, in the first step of translating the source code of one single file in Linux kernel to LLVM bitcode file, I got stuck.

The command I am using is:

```
clang -Iinclude/path -c -emit-llvm one_single_file_in_linux_kernel \
      -o bitcode_file.bc
```

The search path for `clang` is correct, but there are other errors, such as `__always_inline` not found. I think there should be some other flags I should use, but I don't know.

Has anyone have encountered this problem?

Comment: Where is that macro defined and how is it defined? Is the definition wrapped in some `#if` clause? Maybe just adding some `__clang__` will help.

Comment: Actually they are pretty random. I only looked into one such error and following is what I found:

Comment: Clang supports GCC-style attributes (in this case, likely `__attribute__((always_inline))`), so as long as you get the definition included correctly you should be fine.

Comment: the .c file includes an .h file named fls64.h which has a function as follows

Comment: static __always_inline int fls64(...), however, this fls64.h doesn't include the compiler.h file which specifies the macro `__always_inline`

Comment: Is it supposed to be included via `-include`, then? You have to get the definition somehow...